# PySpark Set up on Colab

Tags: pyspark, google-colaboratory

In the process of PySpark set up on the Google Colab I used to implement this code snippet:

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.2.0/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
!tar xf spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
!pip install -q findspark
```

And there was not a problem until yesterday. It used to be done in less than 10 seconds. Today, it has been more than 30 minutes and I am waiting for it to finish running. It gets stuck on the code line below:

```
!wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.2.0/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
```

I am really new in PySpark.

Comment: this has nothing to do with pyspark. using `!` means you're running code on shell. you could try reloading the notebook and restart your runtime.

Answer (score 0):

With `wget -q` you don't see `wget`'s output. Try to run the same command without the option `-q` and see what happens. Keep in mind that the file you're trying to download is ~287M so it might take a while ...

If you just want to use PySpark and do not need to manage your own Spark engine, you can download PySpark with `pip`:

```
!pip install pyspark
```

The PySpark distribution comes with its own Spark engine. To submit jobs use `spark-submit`. No need to set any environment variables.

If you need a specific Spark/PySpark (for instance here 3.3) version use:

```
!PYSPARK_HADOOP_VERSION=3 pip install pyspark
```

(see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html)

Also, you don't need to install Java in order to run PySpark on Google Colab because Java is already there. You can check that Java is in the path and that it has the required version (11). You can see this by running the following commands:

```
!which java
# Out: 
# /usr/bin/java

!java -version
# Out:
# openjdk version "11.0.20.1" 2023-08-24
# OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
# OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```